# $\epsilon - \delta$ proof of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

My goal is to make $ \left| \frac{1-\cos x}{x} \right|< \epsilon $ by finding bounds for the function. Now, we know that
$$ \left| \frac{1-\cos x}{x} \right|< \frac{2}{ \left| x \right| } $$
We want this to be smaller than $\epsilon$, hence $\frac{2}{ \left| x \right| }<\epsilon \implies \left| x \right|> \frac{2}{\epsilon} $ $$ $$ **Now the proof begins from here:**$\ $
Let any $\epsilon >0$ and choose $\delta>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$. Then whenever $0< \left| x \right|<\delta$ $\ \ $implies $$ \left| \frac{1-\cos x}{x} \right|\le \frac{2}{ \left| x \right| }  $$ Now I am stuck here, I want this last inequality to be smaller than $\frac{2}{ \delta }  $ which it is not since $ \left| x \right|<\delta$ $\ \ $. It would complete the proof if $\frac{2}{ \left| x \right| } <\frac{2}{ \delta }<\frac{2}{ \frac{2}{\epsilon} }<\epsilon   $

Comment: Your starting inequality is not the best.

Comment: Your approach is to be used when you want to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1-\cos x) /x=0$ and not when $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

You can use the fact that

$$1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2(\frac x2)$$

and

$$|\sin(X)|\le |X|$$

Comment: yeah i know that but what is wrong with my proof?

Comment: @jiren your proof will not lead you to a conclusion because you have found a lower bound on $x$ instead of an upper one

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing actually wrong with your proof, it's just that, as you have noted, it doesn't help you get where you want. You want an upper bound for $|x|$ , not a lower one.